# Problema ao Trazer dados do banco para o html

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js

ola gente estou fazendo um projeto da escola e gostaria de uma ajuda nessa parte, aqui deve acontecer o seguinte, quando o cliente selecionar o atendente no select Serviço deve ser listado os serviços relacionados com a atendente e logo a pós parecer o valor do mesmo.

ate  momento consegui fazer parecer as atendentes porem não consigo fazer parecer os serviços relacionas a elas e o valor dos mesmo.

estou usando express, node.js, mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo html do select:

```html
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="container" id="informacoesagendamento">
    <div class="container" id="all">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Atendente 
                    <select class="simple" id="atendente">
                        <option>Selecione a Atendente</option>
                        <% dadosAdm.forEach(function(row){%>
                        <option value="<%= row.cod_adm%>"><%= row.nome_adm%></option>
                        <% });%>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="serv">Serviço</div>
                    <select class="simple" id="servico">
                        <option>Selecione o Serviço</option>
                        <% var e = document.getElementById('atendente').value;
                            var itemSelecionado = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
                            %>
                        <% dadosAdm.forEach(function(row){
                            if(row.cod_adm === itemSelecionado){
                            %>
                        <option value="<%= row.cod_adm%>"><%= row.nome_adm%></option>
                        <%} });%>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Data <input type="date" id="data">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="HD">Horários Disponíveis</div>
                    <select class="simple" id="horariosD">
                        <option>Selecione o Horário</option>
                        <option></option>
                        <option></option>
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Valor Total <input type="text" id="valor" disabled="">
                </td>
            </tr>
    </div>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="btnConfirmar"><b>Confirmar</b></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="btnEditar"><b>Editar</b></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="btnCancelar"><b>Cancelar</b></button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="btnNovoAgend"><b>Novo Agendamento</b></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
```

e esse é o codigo js(express(ejs):

```js
router.get('/agendamento', function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.session.user){
    res.redirect("loginCli");
  } else {
    var dadosAdm;
    conn.query('SELECT cod_adm, nome_adm FROM bdlabella.tbadministrador', (err, results) => {

      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      };

      agendamento.procurar().then(resultado =>{

      res.render('TelaAgendamento', { 
        title: 'Tela Agendamento - La Belle',
        dadosAdm: results,
        dadosSer: resultado
      }); 

    }).catch(err => {
      loginClin.render(req, res, err.message || err);
    });

   });
  }
});
```

esse é o erro que esta dando na tela do navegador:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando usar uma API do navegador no lado do servidor. O que você está tentando fazer na linha abaixo é errado.

> ```
> var e = document.getElementById('atendente').value;
> ```

Isso por que você está tentando usar uma API do navegador (`document`) no lado do servidor (dentro da *view*). Ao usar Node.js, precisamos saber que, apesar de estarmos usando a mesma linguagem (JavaScript), as API's nem sempre são compartilhadas.

Portanto, a sua mensagem de erro diz que `documet` é `undefined` por que ela não existe no ambiente do Node.js. Pertence exclusivamente ao browser.

Comment: sim, e como deveria fazer então

Comment: Você deve fazer esse tipo de manipulação no lado do cliente (usando `<script>`, por exemplo).